# add addEventListener to IE7 via .htc

Tags: interface, internet-explorer-7, element, addeventlistener

I know in IE8 you can extend the `Element Interface` so you can abstract attachEvent/detachEvent, such as...

```
if (!window.addEventListener) {
    // Internet Explorer 8 provides access to its 'Element' Interface…

    window.Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture) {
        this.attachEvent('on' + type, listener);
    }

    window.Element.prototype.removeEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture) {
        this.detachEvent('on' + type, listener);
    }
}
```

...but I'm not sure how to implement this in IE7, although I've heard it's possible via a .htc file?

Can any way show me how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Prototype.js, AFAIK, got around this by adding its methods directly to an element (whenever called via `$()`), instead of its prototype, which doesn't work.

If you're looking for a hack to make this work have a look here: http://blog.motane.lu/2007/09/20/elementprototype-in-ie/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried it earlier but couldn't get it to work?